# Opening Spotify app from my reactnative/expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, spotify

I would like to open Spotify from inside my react-native (expo) app. I currently use WebBrowser; which opens up, unsurprisingly, a new browser, displaying the playlist.

Has anyone found a simple way of launching the Spotify *app* from within Expo/RctNtv?

```
 _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('http://open.spotify.com/playlist/{id});
    this.setState({ result });
  };

<Button
          style={styles.paragraph}
          title="Open Spotify"
          onPress={this._handlePressButtonAsync}
        />
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't launch an app within another app. You can only navigate the User from your app to Spotify via URL schemes.

Comment: Use the `Linking` module to open Spotify URLs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#openurl

More information on how to structure URLs here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/content-linking-guide/

Comment: Thanks, these are separate iOS & Android fixes, but as I am trying to keep this as a simple Expo/ReactNative app I will probably just keep the WebBrowser method I have, it does work in terms of  giving the user an ability to listen to a playlist, just in a mobile browser not the app. Which is fine for what I need. Thanks for the response.